# Is there a way to request $http for an interceptor?

Tags: angularjs

The idea is to get a data from another source in certain cases, so I have this stub:

```
factory("interceptor", function ($q, $location, $http) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise;
    }
}
```

which fails with

> [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: interceptor <- $http

Also tried to inject $injector and retrieve $http using that, with same results. Any ideas?

.config is nothing but declaration:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('interceptor');
});
```

Comment: why do you need to inject $http into the interceptor?

Comment: As stated in question:  to get a data from another source. E.g. requiest is to /url/one.js, I want to replace it with data from /url/two.js.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Inject `$injector` to `interceptor`:

Use it to get `$http` inside the returned object within callback functions.

Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/AnoVUPi/2/edit)

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptor');
});

app.factory("interceptor", function ($q, $location, $injector) {
  return {
    request: function(config){      
      var $http = $injector.get('$http');
      console.dir($http);
      return config;
    }
  }
});

app.run(function($http){
  $http.get('/')
});
```

Comment: can I make an $http request inside an interceptor using this? I need to do that

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the Angular source code the better answer is such. $http method is accessible without dependency injection so the trick is to NOT INJECT $http and to simply use it. Like such:

```
Right Way

retryModule = angular.module('retry-call', [])

# Do not inject $http
retryModule.factory 'RetryCall', ($q)->
  # More object keys
  'responseError': (response)=>
    # Just use $http without injecting it
    $http(response.config)
    $q.reject(response)

retryModule.config ['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('RetryCall');
]

Wrong Way

# Do not do it this way.
retryModule.factory 'RetryCall', ($q,$http)->
```

Comment: That's a pretty tall claim, but it seems neat. I wasn't able to use `$http` in my interceptor without getting it from `$injector`, but I may have misunderstood your point. Any chance you have a fiddle or could point to where you learned this from the source?