# inject $route into a http interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to inject custom header to every API request. When I am providing some hard coded text it works.

**Working code**

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    var requestInterceptor = ['$q', '$rootScope', 
        function ($q, $rootScope) {
            var interceptorInstance = {
                request: function (config) {
                    config.headers['X-MyApp-CustomHeader'] = "foobar"; 
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                }
            };
            return interceptorInstance;
        }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);
}]);
```

**Not working code**

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    var requestInterceptor = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$route',
        function ($q, $rootScope, $route ) {
            var interceptorInstance = {
                request: function (config) {
                    config.headers['X-MyApp-CustomHeader'] = $route.current.params.CustomParameter; 
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                }
            };
            return interceptorInstance;
        }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);
}]);
```

**Error**, When trying to inject `$route`

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $route <- $http
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$injector/cdep?p0=%24route%20%3C-%20%24http

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2367).

Check out my answer:  [Is there a way to request $http for an interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119016/is-there-a-way-to-request-http-for-an-interceptor/21119959#21119959)

`$route` depends on `$http` which in turn depends on the interceptors:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    var requestInterceptor = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$injector',
        function ( $q, $rootScope, $injector ) {
            var interceptorInstance = {
                request: function (config) {
                    var $route = $injector.get('$route');
                    config.headers['X-MyApp-CustomHeader'] = $route.current.params.CustomParameter; 
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                }
            };
            return interceptorInstance;
        }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);
}]);
```

#### what is $injector?

- You must read [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$injector)
- And see this [great tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnSb4ebdjrk)

> $injector is used to retrieve object instances as defined by provider , instantiate types, invoke methods, and load modules.

Internally, angular.js would use $injector to invoke your methods ( config / run blocks ) with all the dependencies injected. This happens automatically so you rarely need to worry about it.
In cases where $injector fails to resolve your dependencies you can do it manually.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The `$route` doesn't contain the current route on it, it just contains the routes, a reload function and the updateParams function. Angular 1.5.7.