# AngularJS change URL in module.config

Tags: angularjs, restangular, angular-routing

I use `Restangular` in my angularjs App & use `setErrorInterceptor` to handle response error in one place. I want to redirect user to login page if an error occured. I know that the only `providers` & `constants` are injectable in configuration phase.

```
var app = angular.module('ourstandApp', ['ngRoute', 'restangular', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies', 'angularFileUpload']);
    // Global configuration

    app.config(function (RestangularProvider, baseRequestConfig, $routeProvider, urlsProvider) {
        var getBaseRequestUrl = function () {
            return baseRequestConfig.protocol + "://" + baseRequestConfig.hostName + ":" + baseRequestConfig.portNumber + baseRequestConfig.resourcePath;
    }
        var initializeRoute = function () {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                controller: LoginController,
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }

        initializeRoute();
        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(getBaseRequestUrl());
        RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(function (resp) {
            goToLogin();  //  i want to change url to login page
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: What sort of errors are you expecting? 404, 500, resource not found? there are ng routing events for these. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route such as `$routeChangeError`. Then usually I would have access to the $location and use `$location.path('YOUR PATH')`;

Comment: all 4xx and 5xx errors. @Matthew.Lothian
i want to handle errors in one place and restangular gives me this feature but the problem is with changing path in .config() method

Comment: I'm not familiar with Restangular but making a general catch all i maybe not the way to go. i'll give an example of how i have set this up before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the correct way for handling this problem is configuring restangular in `run` method of angularjs

```
app.run(Restangular , $location){
    Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function (resp) {
        $location.path('/login');
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Small tip for other viewers of the answer. You can use `$state.go(...)` instead of `$location.path(...)`. You're in the run block anyway.

Answer (score 4):

#### Inject `$injector` to the config block and invite `$location` when needed:

```
RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(function (resp) {
   var $location = $injector.get('$location');
   $location.path('/login');
   return false;
});
```

#### Also check my other answers:

- [inject $route into a http interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229177/inject-route-into-a-http-interceptor/21229282#21229282)
- [Is there a way to request $http for an interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119016/is-there-a-way-to-request-http-for-an-interceptor/21119959#21119959)

Comment: tnx for your solution but it throws this error:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $location

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to be more specific about how resources are requested. In this excerpt from a project i am using the `resolve` option of `routeProvider.when` to look up a resource based on path input and injecting the result as `ArticleRequest` before resolving the route.

If the api calls the route fails and the `$routeChangeError` event is fired

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'TEMPLATE_PATH',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, TEMPLATE_PATH) {

    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: TEMPLATE_PATH + 'views/Home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    }).
    when('/:slug/:nocache?', {
        templateUrl: TEMPLATE_PATH + 'views/Article.html',
        controller: 'ArticleCtrl',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
        resolve: {
            ArticleRequest: ['$http', '$route', function ($http, $route) {
                return $http.post('/api/article/GetArticleBySlug',
                    {
                        slug: $route.current.params.slug,
                        nocache: !!$route.current.params.nocache && $route.current.params.nocache == 'preview'
                    });
            }]
        }
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);   

}]);
```

Here is a very simple implementation of the `$routeChangeError` handler

```
App.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (e, current, previous, rejection) {

        console.log("ROUTE ERROR:", current, previous, rejection);
        // you might redirect here based on some logic
        $location.path('[YOUR PATH]');

    });

}]);
```

and here is the controller

```
ViewControllers.controller('ArticleCtrl', 
['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'ArticleRequest',
function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, ArticleRequest) {

    console.log(ArticleRequest);

}]);
```

Is something like this usefull in you case with Restangular?

Comment: tnx you . but i use Restangular for its awesome features that enables me to filter response & request.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to redirect the user to a login page based on a status code returned to you by the server? Like a 404 or 403?

If that's the case this is how I handle redirects on a 404 and 403 using `setErrorInterceptor` in one of my apps. This may not be the best way to do this, but It's been working just fine so far for me.

```
app.config(['RestangularProvider', function (RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(function (response) {
        // Redirect the user to the login page if they are not logged in.
        if (response.status == '403' && response.data.detail == 'Authentication credentials were not provided.') {
            var next = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;

            window.location.href = '/accounts/login/?next=' + next;
        }

        // Redirect the user on a 404.
        if (response.status == '404') {
            // Redirect to a 404 page.
            window.location.href = '/#/';
        }

        return response;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: tnx for your solution . you use pure javascript code to handle this problem