# Redirect with ui-router in setInterceptor Restangular

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router, restangular

i'm struggling to find a way to redirect to a state when an error occurs. I'm handling the error responses with the `setErrorInterceptor` of Restangular as the following:

```
angular.module('app.http').factory('RestangularCustom',RestangularCustom);

RestangularCustom.$inject = ['Restangular','HandlerBag','$state','notify'];

function RestangularCustom(Restangular,HandlerBag,$state,notify) {

        Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {

            // Add the error to the handler bag
            HandlerBag.catchError(response);

            // User can't access if already authenticated
            if (response.status === 403 && response.data.response && response.data.response.auth === true) {
                console.log('authenticated'); // it trigger correctly
                $state.go('app.home');
                return false;
            }
            if (response.status === 403 && response.data.context === 'authentication') {
                console.log('auth error'); // it trigger correctly
                $state.go('auth.login');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                notify({
                    classes: 'error',
                    message: response.data.message || 'Server Error'
                });
            }

            return true; // error not handled
        });
    }
```

The following code handle the errors correctly, triggering the `console.log()` but it doesn't redirect to my wanted states.

I read the following already posted question:

[AngularJS change URL in module.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445886/angularjs-change-url-in-module-config)

it suggest to set the `setErrorInterceptor` in the `run` function, i tried that as well without luck, it doesn't redirect either. What's wrong with it?

Comment: did you tried `$location.path('/app/home');`?

Comment: thanks for the reply but i tried and does not work

Comment: Give a one more try by writing inside app.run place state inside $rootScope by doing $rootScope.$state = $state & then do $rootScope.$state.go inside interceptor code

Comment: I tried how you said doing as the following: http://pastebin.com/zUEx8xfx but still doesn't redirect. if you have other thoughts please let me know, thanks a lot