# Make $http request before any other request Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

Whenever I make an $http request before any request I get the popular Circular dependency problem. I've seen these questions before:

- [I need two instances of AngularJS $http service or what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681654/i-need-two-instances-of-angularjs-http-service-or-what?answertab=active#tab-top)
- [Is there a way to request $http for an interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119016/is-there-a-way-to-request-http-for-an-interceptor/21119959#comment60853911_21119959)

I truly don't know if these questions above are trying to get the same thing I'm trying to achieve. I want to make an $http request to check the integrity of my JWT token, I need to do this on my server side. If the token has expired I need to get the user another token.

Here's my code

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);

app.factory('requestInterceptor', ['$q', '$localStorage', '$location', function($q, $localStorage, $location)
{
    var requestInterceptor = {};

    requestInterceptor.request = function(config)
    {
//        $http
//        ({
//           url : 'api/token',
//           method: 'GET',
//           headers : { Authorization : $localStorage.token}
//        }).then(function(response){
//           $localStorage.token = response.data.token;
//        },function(response){
//           $localStorage.token = null;
//           $location.path('/');
//        });           

        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($localStorage.token)
        {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
        }
        return config;        
    };

    requestInterceptor.responseError =  function (response)
    {
        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403)
        {
            $location.path('/signin');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    };

    return requestInterceptor;
}]);
```

**NOTE**

Can't use [Angular-JWT](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt)

Answer (score 0):

Try to abstract token validation into a different service. I didnt test it^ but it should work.

```
app.factory('auth', ['$http', '$localStorage', '$location', function($http, $localStorage, $location){
  return {
    validateToken: function() {
      return $http({
        url : 'api/token',
        method: 'GET',
        headers : { Authorization : $localStorage.token}
      }).then(function(response){
        $localStorage.token = response.data.token;
        return response.data.token;
      },function(response){
        $localStorage.token = null;
        $location.path('/');
      });       
    }
  }
}]);

app.factory('requestInterceptor', ['auth', function(auth){
  var requestInterceptor = {};

  requestInterceptor.request = function(config){
    if (!config.url.startsWith('api/token')) {
      auth.validateToken().then(function(token){
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
        return config;   
      });
    } else {
      return config;   
    }
  };

  return requestInterceptor;
}]);
```

Comment: I get $http not defined. And if I include the $http service I get the circular dependency problem